# Malformed line error fixed update/ upgrade errors:

Tags: upgrade, updates

I fixed the malformed line error in my sources list, and was able to run the `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. When I ran the update these errors came up:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

    W: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/trusty-getdeb/apps/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should I do?

Then, when I ran the upgrade, these errors showed up:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-windows-live libnvpair1 libupstart1 libuutil1 libzfs2
  libzpool2 thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb
  thunderbird-locale-en-us
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers grub-common grub-efi-amd64
  grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub2-common libldb1
  liboxideqt-qmlplugin liboxideqtcore0 liboxideqtquick0 libsmbclient
  libwbclient0 linux-headers-generic linux-headers-lowlatency
  linux-image-lowlatency linux-lowlatency linux-signed-generic
  linux-signed-image-generic openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless
  oxideqt-codecs-extra python-cupshelpers python-ldb python-samba qpdf samba
  samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules samba-libs
  samba-vfs-modules shim shim-signed smbclient system-config-printer-gnome
  ubuntu-minimal winbind
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: You haven't told us what Ubuntu release you are running, which is pretty basic information that would be appreciated. I see reference to trusty (14.04) is your error message, but assuming that is your release could create other issues so you should tell us.  Google 32bit support was dropped years ago, so that line should be removed (deleted to commented out) in my opinion. The archive.getdeb.net I don't know, but I get errors on my browser too, so I'd remove it (it's one you've added, so I'd look for whatever notes/documentation/comments you left for yourself on why you added it!)..

Comment: Duplicate source errors I'd hope would be pretty self explanatory, remove reference to them (my default would be adding a "#" at the start of the line and turning it into a comment; as it's easy to undo if you make a mistake) - but it's your system & your choice.

Comment: yes, 14.04, and I didn't install it- someone else did. This is all very difficult for me to understand as I am a beginner and have absolutely no understanding of how to work this operating system or what any of it means, so I'd appreciate it if you'd loose the sarcasm and snide remarks. It must be nice to have all the information you need to trouble shoot problems like this with it being so easy and self-explanatory and all. For me that's not the case.

Comment: "Google 32bit support was dropped years ago, so that line should be removed"  HOW?

Comment: "The archive.getdeb.net I don't know, but I get errors on my browser too, so I'd remove it"  HOW?

Comment: "Duplicate source errors I'd hope would be pretty self explanatory, remove reference to them (my default would be adding a "#" at the start of the line and turning it into a comment"  HOW?

Comment: Your main sources are in `/etc/apt/sources.list` but you can also create files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`  (this is empty on new install, any here are added by users).  You just edit those files, for me that's `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` as I like vim as my editor. You can replace 'vim' with any editor you like, eg. nano, joe..  All lines with "#" are treated as comments, thus allowing me to note why & when I add something, or why I commented something (i usually comment instead of deleting as easy to back-out if it was a mistake). For duplicates you comment one.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions two days in a row. I spent a lot of time answering your other question, with the result that you needed to reinstall Ubuntu... and you didn't even vote/accept that answer. If you're not sure what you're doing with Ubuntu, a clean fresh install would help you a lot.